# Split html document while maintaining inner tags

Tags: php, html, split, html-encode

I'm working on an e-shop. At some point in my code I have to show attributes and descriptions for many products in a single page.Attributes are a table and description can contain simple text and table,li,br tags etc...These which are stored in the database as html encoded string. So in my php file I load them from the db and decode them like this.

```
$description=html_entity_decode($description_from_db, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$attributes=html_entity_decode($attributes_from_db, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Later on I just do `echo $description;` an they are shown properly. 
All this HAS TO BE PRINTABLE and here comes the challenge.

When the attributes table and the description are long enough the exceed the printable page height and they get cut in half looking realy ugly. What I want to do is split the $description and $attributes strings and echo them with page breaks between the pieces where neccesary. The problem is that this must be done with respect to the tags inside these strings. I can't for example break the string in the middle of a tr tag.

Is there a way to break these strings maintaining the html elements that they contain intact ? I'm thinking it must be possible since html editors show a warning when a tag has been left unclosed.

Comment: Page breaks in HTML? eh?

Comment: page breaks for printing. not for viewing on screen

Comment: Aaah, that explains it.

Comment: the whole point is to improve how the document looks when printed

Comment: I understand, regretably you don't have any control over that (but see my answer below). You should look at using something like PDF documents.

Comment: I have "invented" a way to insert page breaks when needed in the tags that i write my own. and it works well. if i manage to split these large divs the right way my problem will be solved

Comment: You'll have to write something yourself obviously. Nobody can know how you want to break things up. You'll need an HTML parser..that's all anyone can tell you.

Comment: I want to break them into as many pieces as possible ! I have no other criteria

Answer (score 0):

You can put page breaks in your HTML code, then the HTML will choose where to break itself:

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/page-break

http://davidwalsh.name/css-page-breaks

Comment: I am aware of that. The problem is that I have no control over these strings. They are allready stored by others in the database for 1500 products without printing in mind. So manipulating them in code seems the only way to do it.

Comment: Well, the only thing you can do then is search for possible locations to put these page-breaks. For instance in a <div>. <p>, <tr> and <br>. But it will be difficult to make it work right all the time. You're the only one who can find out.